# Nginx não Reconhece arquivos da Pasta?

Tags: php, docker, nginx

Estou trabalhando em um sistema Web e utilizando o `Docker` com `Nginx`. O Nginx não está reconhecendo as imagens que compões o sistema nem tão pouco os arquivos que compõe o `Bootstrap`.

Segue abaixo o arquivo default do `Nginx`:

```
server {
listen 80;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.php index.html index.html;

server_name 192.168.0.18;

location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
   }
}
```

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Os arquivos são carregados? Eles são interpretados pelo navegador? Ocorre o erro 404? O endereço dos arquivos está sendo apontado corretamente no HTML?

Comment: Vadeir Psr, não ocorre o erro 404, o navegador não consegue interpretar e estão apontados corretamente no HTML.

Comment: utilize `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;` e inclua o arquivo `mime.types` em sua configuração, por exemplo: `include /etc/nginx/mime.types;`

Comment: Como criou o container?